# Graphics card doesn't output

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I had a fully working computer set up with a Corsair CX600M PSU, and a Radeon HD 5450 GPU, but I needed a more powerful GPU, so I bought a Gigabyte R9 280x, (This one: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5266#ov), and put it in, but when I turn the computer on, the GPU produces no output to the DVI or HDMI, but the fans turn. When I press the off button, the computer immediately turns off, so it probably didn't boot into Windows either. I've got the Catalyst 13.1 drivers installed, and I installed the drivers supplied in the DVD. I bought the card on ebay as new from the box, and the listing has now been removed. The motherboard is a Medion MD-7***, and the GPU is in a PCI-E 2.0 x16 slot. When I put the old GPU back in, it works fine.

UPDATE:
I got a replacement from the seller, it doesn't work either.

Comment: What else is plugged into your sytem? How many hard drives,optical, USB,and etc

Comment: I assume you saw the 6 and 8 pin connector for power on the back of the video card and plugged power cables from the PSU into them?

Comment: According to the Gigabyte specs. the power requirement is 600W. Since your PSU is rated as 600W it seems something may not be getting enough power. It would be helpful to get the actual operating voltage and current draw of the graphics card, since overall power may be misleading. BTW, no beep or POST?

Comment: @user3169 Power requirements are accounting for maximum system power draw with some headroom. There is no way he's coming close to that unless OP isn't telling us he's got a NAS farm inside his box and a ton of different cathodes running or something.

Comment: @Matthew, have you tried verifying that it's NOT a GPU problem? The one you bought could be DOA. I'm not sold on the PSU being the problem as other users have stated. You can google your PSU and GPU and see there are many users running the same configuration just fine.

Comment: @cybernard When I put the new GPU in, I had nothing connected but the power and display cable. The PCI-e 6 and 8 pins were also connected

Comment: @user3169 To see if this was the case, I unplugged one of the PCI-E power cables. The motherboard beeped in a pattern which meant that the GPU was not detected.

Comment: @BenSampica I got a replacement, didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the GPU in another desktop, and it worked once the same PSU was in. I think the problem was either a motherboard compatibility problem, or the one of the connections on the PCI bus was damaged. The desktop it worked in was very similar to the one it didn't; it was the same MD-7000 series, but with a different number at the end. It also had an AMD rather then Intel CPU.

Answer (score 2):

The possibility remains your PSU might not be enough.  I looked up the PSU in questions and it has some interesting inconsistencies.  It says 600w, but then according to the diagram it has 3.3/5v with 130w and 12v at 552 when you add  then together you get error.  The grand total should be 600w so you don't have as many amps at 12 volts as they say.[image: corasir psu]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 600W PSU recommendation from Gigabyte is usually to make sure the GPU still has enough power if the other components are very power-hungry. My setup probably consumed 100-300w less then the maximum, according to online calculators.